# yii2 asset folder is not writable by web process

Tags: yii2, centos7, yii2-basic-app

I've set the permission 777 to assets folder already, but it's still not writable.
[image: assets folder is not writable]

please help!!!

Comment: Something has been writing to your assets folder, the screenshot shows it has 36 directories in it! Have you changed something in your code recently?

Comment: I just uploaded something inside assets folder via FTP

Comment: I think its user permission issue.Please check user when you upload assests via FTP and then change file permission from FTP.

Comment: I've tried change the folder owner&group to apache already, but it's still not working. Any idea?

Comment: Do a recursive change of everything inside the folder `chmod -R 777 assets`

Comment: Do somethig like `chown -R siclinic:www-data assets`